# Calculate age: PHP vs MySQL, which method is better?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, optimization, query-optimization

I have around 500,000 records of personal profile in MySQL database containing a birthdate column (dob). Since I had to get the ages for each profile, I needed to calculate it dynamically which I can either do via PHP `(date_diff(date_create($dob), date_create('today'))->y)` or through SQL `('SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob, CURDATE()) AS age')`.
Which of the two is faster or more preferred especially if I have hundreds of thousands of rows?

Comment: I'd throw out the wild guess that doing it via mysql will be faster. You can benchmark this easily though and I advise you to do that.

Comment: If you want to select only records of a specific DOB then you would of course use SQL. If you filter on that column always use SQL because it reduces the records you process at the source.

Comment: Are you going to get all `500,000` records at once?

Comment: You could test this as quickly as asking us

Comment: vivek: I had to split the records 500-2000 per page to make it viewable. But sometimes I need to process all of the records from the back-end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a test:

Create a table with 100K random dates

```
drop table if exists birthdays;
create table birthdays (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    dob date
);
insert into birthdays (dob)
    select '1950-01-01' + interval floor(rand(1)*68*365) day as dob
    from information_schema.COLUMNS c1
       , information_schema.COLUMNS c2
       , information_schema.COLUMNS c3
    limit 100000
;
```

Run this PHP script

```php
<?php
header('Content-type: text/plain');
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", "test","");

### SQL
$starttime = microtime(true);

$stmt = $db->query("SELECT id, dob, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob, CURDATE()) AS age FROM birthdays");
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$runtime = microtime(true) - $starttime;
echo "SQL: $runtime \n";

### PHP
$starttime = microtime(true);

$stmt = $db->query("SELECT id, dob FROM birthdays");
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $row->age = date_diff(date_create($row->dob), date_create('today'))->y;
}

$runtime = microtime(true) - $starttime;
echo "PHP: $runtime \n";
```

Result:

```
SQL: 0.19094109535217 
PHP: 1.203684091568
```

It looks like the SQL solution is **6 times faster**. But that is not quite true. If we remove the code which calculates the age from both solutions, we will get something like *0.1653790473938*. That means the overhead for SQL is *0.025 sec*, while for PHP it is *1.038 sec*. So SQL is **40 times faster** in this test.

Note: There are faster ways to calculate the age in PHP. For example

```
$d = date('Y-m-d');
$row->age = substr($d, 0, 4) - substr($row->dob, 0, 4) - (substr($row->dob, 5) > substr($d, 5) ? 1 : 0);
```

is like four times faster - while `date('Y-m-d')` consumes more than 80% of the time. If you find a way to avoid any date function, you might get close to the performance of MySQL.

Answer (score 3):

In general, the best approach is to do such calculations on the server.

The ideal approach would be to use a generated column.  This has been available since MySQL 5.7.5, and would be expressed as:

```
alter table t add age unsigned as 
    (TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob, CURDATE()));
```

Alas, you can only use *deterministic* functions for generated columns.  `curdate()` and `now()` are not deterministic, because their values can change with each call.

The next best thing is to use a view:

```
create view v_t as
    select t.*,
           TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob, CURDATE())
    from t;
```

Then, when you query the view, you'll have the `age`.  This is true no matter where you query it.  And it is the same logic everywhere.

The only caveat to doing the calculation on the server is that it uses server time, rather than local application time.  If that is an issue, then that is a strong argument for doing the calculation locally.

Answer (score -1):

if you want get all 500,000 records you should do this in MySql because performance is better than PHP

but, if you want get some of that data (for example 10 records) , do that with PHP it's better to handle. and performance not different